# Call to undefined method App\Models\PDF::loadView()

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf, laravel-dompdf

```
controller
```

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Pdf;

use App\Models\PDF;
use App\Models\TestMcq;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class TestPdfController extends Controller
{
    public function createPDF($id) {
        $TestMcq = TestMcq::where('test_id', $id)->get();
        $data = [
            'title' => 'Welcome to ItSolutionStuff.com',
            'date' => date('m/d/Y')
        ];
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.test', $data);
        return $pdf->download('test.pdf');
      }
}
```

```
web.php
```

```
Route::get('/test/pdf/{id}', [TestPdfController::class, 'createPDF']);
```

```
'providers' => ServiceProvider::defaultProviders()->merge([
        Mccarlosen\LaravelMpdf\LaravelMpdfServiceProvider::class,

        /*
         * Package Service Providers...
         */

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

        Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesServiceProvider::class,
    ])->toArray(),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Aliases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
    | is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
    | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
    |
    */

    'aliases' => Facade::defaultAliases()->merge([
        // 'Example' => App\Facades\Example::class,
        'PDF' => Mccarlosen\LaravelMpdf\Facades\LaravelMpdf::class,
        'DataTables' => Yajra\DataTables\Facades\DataTables::class,
    ])->toArray(),
```

I didn't know why gives me an error ?

...............................................................................................

I don't know why it gives me this error. I tried to deal with it a lot, but it gives me this strange error. I made another file and put exactly the same things in it and it worked, but I need to add it to this project

Comment: you defined the PDF facade as model 'use App\Models\PDF' instead of facade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDF doesn't exist in app/Models folder. Try this:

```
use App\Models\PDF; // replace this with "use PDF" (for calling via alias) OR "use Mccarlosen\LaravelMpdf\Facades\LaravelMpdf as PDF" (for direct calling)
```